# How to prevent text from going outside of an element?

Tags: html, css

this is my css

```
.newsContent {
position: relative;
background-color: red;
min-height: 200px;
width: 300px;}
```

[image]

How can I not bypass the border of div?

Comment: try word-wrap: break-word;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a new CSS3 property which does what you need.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are speaking about is the `overflow` of the div element.

For more details use: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

```
visible  |  The overflow is not clipped. It renders outside the element's box. (DEFAULT)
hidden   |  The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible
scroll   |  The overflow is clipped, but a scroll-bar is added to see the rest of the content
auto     |  If overflow is clipped, a scroll-bar should be added to see the rest of the content
inherit  |  Specifies that the value of the overflow property should be inherited from the parent element
```

If you want to cut it off, use `overflow: hidden;`

Now if you are talking about the text breaking, just look at the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

One way is by using `word-wrap: break-word;` on `.newsContent`

```
.newsContent {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wETGx/